# CheckboxColumn в GridView

Tags: yii2, checkbox

У меня есть таблица со следующими полями:

```
integer $ID_REC
string $NAME_TOPIC
integer $RANDOM
integer $MAX_TIME
string $DT_UP
integer $STATUS
```

В переменной $RANDOM в БД у меня записаны данные либо 0, либо 1.
Как мне вывести в GridView колонку в виде CheckBox для поля $RANDOM? Потому что если я вывожу таким образом, то у меня все чек-боксы пустые.

```
<?php Pjax::begin(); ?>    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'ID_REC',
            'NAME_TOPIC',
            [
                'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn',
                'checkboxOptions' => function ($model, $key, $index, $column) {
                    return ['value' => $model->RANDOM];
                }
            ],
            'RANDOM',
            'MAX_TIME:text',
            'DT_UP',
            'STATUS',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось довольно просто. Чек бокс сам себя не отметит, нужно просто было указать условие:

```
return ['value' => $model->RANDOM, 'checked' => $model->RANDOM];
```